# YiiBoster Extended grid sum operation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, sum, yii-booster

I'm using the extend from Yiiboster (last version)

and I want to add a Total to an invoice and I want to do a TbSumOperation but without success so far

I don't know how to specify from which column on columns to sum

So far I only get a blank rectangle

I just copy pasted the example from the page and put it after columns=>(),

```
   'extendedSummary' => array(
        'title' => 'Total Employee Hours',
        'columns' => array(
            'hours' => array('label'=>'Total Hours', 'class'=>'TbSumOperation')
        )
    ),
    'extendedSummaryOptions' => array(
        'class' => 'well pull-right',
        'style' => 'width:300px'
    ),
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at this line from your init method

```
'dataProvider' => $gridDataProvider,
```

It is result what you do query and bind into grid, the column name which you would like to sum should be put in `extendedSummary.

Example: I want to sum working hours of my employees. My employee table has column `hours` like this

```
emp_id|name     |hours

1      Kevin     48    
2      Denton    16    
3      Harry     30
```

.

```
$gridDataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('EmployeeModel', array(
                    'criteria' => array('condition' => 'age > 20')));
```

And I should have to put `hours` string into my grid summary setting